# Bundling Link Broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When you create a new ASP.Net MVC4 project, a file is created in App_Start called BundleConfig.cs (where you can create your script and css file bundles.)

At the top of that file is a comment that reads:

```
// For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
```

As far as I can tell, this link is broken. It simply redirects straight to here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Which, as of this writing, has absolutely no information specific to bundling.

Where did it originally go? Where should it go now?

Comment: Actually, this site does have information specific to bundling in the tutorial section:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Usually these links go straight to the relevant details...

Comment: Agreed it should - I just was providing info on the 'no information about bundling' statement.  I would assume that the tutorials were not finalized when the project template was built, so it just goes to MVC.